# How to translate different languages in a column in a dataframe to English using textblob?

Tags: python, dataframe, textblob

I have a `dataframe` in which there is a comments column. The comments are written in different languages including English. I wanted to translate all the comments into English language.

I used the code:

```
df['comments'] = df['comments'].apply(lambda x: x.translate(to = 'en'))
```

The error shown is:

```
TypeError: translate() takes no keyword arguments
```

Comment: Try using `lambda x: TextBlob(x).translate(to='en')`.

Comment: I try using the code. Again, there is an error which says: Not Translated: Translation API returned the input string unchanged.

Comment: Perhaps that's because the comment was already in English.

Comment: So, what approach should I take to solve the issue?

Comment: **IF** the error is because what I said earlier about the comment already being in English is true, you could simply ignore it. Did you verify that's the reason? In Python they can be ignored by using `try` & `except`. What exactly is the type of exception being raised?

Comment: Error is same which i already mentioned. Also, i tried using try and except, still the comments are not translated.

Comment: This is my try except code: try:
    df['comments'] = df['comments'].apply(lambda x: TextBlob(x).translate(to = 'en'))
except:
    print('not translated'). When i run it, it shows not translated.

Comment: Change the last part to be `except Exception as exc:`, then `print(exc)` on the following line. This will print the exception being raised. Once you know that, you can the rewrite the code to handle _just that specific exception_ and instead of printing it, you can put in code to do whatever you want to happen when the comment is already in English.

Comment: I tried the code, but again it is showing Translation API returned the input string unchanged. I also tried to translate only one language that is from french to english by using from_lang. However, still it is showing the same error. I was reading that TextBlob uses Google's Translate API. If we make too many requests, Google Blocks the IP address from accessing its translate service, temporarily. Can the error be due to this issue?

Comment: Yes, too many requests could be the problem. If the exact same test case fails, but then works later on, then it would be a strong indication that's what is going on.

Comment: So for how much time i have to wait because i ran the code yesterday, then i tried it today using the changes you suggested but still same issue.

Comment: I don't know, but 24 hours seems like more than enough — so it sounds like the problem is due to something else. You should contact the TextBlob developer(s) and report the problem to them.